# Looking for simple poll/survey Rails plugin or gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am trying to find a simple poll plugin/gem (the type of single question poll that's usually found in site's sidebar). All plugins that I've found are either too complex (like having their own DSL) or they are out of date (i.e. older than couple years).

Does anyone knows a Rails plugin/gem that handles simple polls?

Comment: I ended up making my own custom poll within the app I was working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own custom solution for a simple poll I needed. Unfortunately, I needed it fast so I wrote it within an app I was working on (i.e. I didn't separate it into gem)

Comment: Anyone still needing a solution for this checkout the Surveyor Gem: https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor. This fork is rails 4+ ready: https://github.com/HeHStudy/surveyor

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [SMeRF](http://smerf.cascadia.com.au/), I'm currently using [Surveyor](https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor) and yes it is complicated. So I recommend you to use SMeRF, it is a lot more simple. But I can't seem to make it work on Rails3. xP

What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: SMerRF doesn't really seem maintained anymore.